# Engine for HTML5 Canvas animations and effects?

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas

I am developing a HTML5 game. The server-side code (node.js, socket.io) is mostly done and I am moving on to polishing the client-side code.

I have been directly drawing tiles/grid on the canvas and moving the player's sprite using context and clearRect etc. I am thinking of drawing simple animations and effects over the tile-map/grid such as:

- Rain, with flashes of lightning, and thunder audio clip.
- Animating some of the tiles. E.g. grass tile has grass blowing in the wind by cycling through frames (like an animated gif).
- Pop up text boxes that are close-able with mouse clicks or keyboard button press.

I have checked out this [long list of JavaScript engines](https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Game-Engines) and tried out CraftyJS and MelonJS but most of these are made for platform or arcade style games, and many of them are not ready for production or are poorly maintained.

Is there a simple, lightweight, production-quality HTML5 canvas engine that can accomplish what I want?

Comment: I personally love [Impact](http://impactjs.com/), but I'm afraid that will not suit your needs since it's a bit too heavy and isn't free...

Comment: @MarcoK - You are right. Impact is too heavy for me. As this is a commercial (indy) project, I have some budget, so not being free is OK. But given that large parts of the code has been written, and I only really need to add animated sprites to the client, I loathe to have to "start over" and work within the confines of Impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [**CreateJS**](http://www.createjs.com); it's a great engine for what you're looking for.

- [EaseJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS) can be used for the Canvas element
- [SoundJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS) for the audio clip which you want played

It's well maintained, but an 1.0 version hasn't been released (yet).

Comment: Update: Thanks for bringing CreateJS up. It does look very well maintained/supported and has multiple relevant tools for sound, preloading, drawing etc. I think I will go with this one.

Comment: Don't forget the extra's you'll get (Tools etc.) and the Sponsors behind it (Adobe, Microsoft etc.), giving the project a higher chance to succeed/to survive!

Comment: Yes. I was tempted to go with cgSceneGraph at first but I saw all the tools and sponsors and decided to go with CreateJS instead. Thank you so much for this, you saved me a lot of search time.

Answer (score 1):

Is it just animated sprites you want to achieve? You can do this easy without the use of a game engine. As for dialog boxes - you could just use dom elements over the canvas.

Here is a sprite class I wrote in javascript - maybe it's of some help :)

```
var FrtlsSprite = Class.extend({
init: function(bitmap, offsetX, offsetY, frameWidth, frameHeight, frameCount, loop){
    this.dtotal=0;
    this.framerate=0.007;
    this.loop = loop;
    this.isPlaying=false;

    this.bitmap = new Image();
    this.bitmap.src = bitmap;
    this.frames= new Array();
    this.currentFrame=0;
    this.endFrame=0;

    for(var i=0;i<frameCount;i++){
        this.frames.push(new FrtlsFrame(offsetX+i*frameWidth, offsetY+0, frameWidth, frameHeight));
    }
},
update: function(dt){
    if(this.isPlaying){
        this.dtotal += dt   //we add the time passed since the last update, probably a very small number like 0.01
        if (this.dtotal >= this.framerate){
            this.dtotal -= this.framerate; 
            this.currentFrame++;
            if(this.currentFrame==this.endFrame){
                if(this.loop == false){
                    this.stop();
                }
                else{
                    this.currentFrame=0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
draw: function(){
    fruitless.ctx.drawImage(this.bitmap, 
                            this.frames[this.currentFrame].pos.x, 
                            this.frames[this.currentFrame].pos.y, 
                            this.frames[this.currentFrame].dimensions.x, 
                            this.frames[this.currentFrame].dimensions.y, 
                            0, 
                            0, 
                            this.frames[this.currentFrame].dimensions.x*fruitless.worldScale, 
                            this.frames[this.currentFrame].dimensions.y*fruitless.worldScale);
},
play:function(frame){
    this.currentFrame=(frame==undefined)?0:frame;
    this.endFrame = this.frames.length-1
    this.isPlaying=true;
},
playTo:function(frame, endFrame){
    this.currentFrame=frame;
    this.endFrame = endFrame;
    this.isPlaying=true;
},

stop:function(frame){
    this.currentFrame=(frame==undefined)?this.currentFrame:frame;
    this.isPlaying=false;
}
```

});

Comment: Thanks for the code. Yes I suppose I can just JQuery the dialog boxes.

Answer (score 1):

[cgSceneGraph](http://gwennaelbuchet.github.com/cgSceneGraph/) will do the job for you.
Look at the [examples web page](http://gwennaelbuchet.github.com/cgSceneGraph/examples.html), there are some examples with animated Sprite. It's a native component of the framework and is really easy to use with several featres like multi animation inside the same instance of the animated sprite, use of spritesheet, ...

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. +1. I actually haven't seen cgSceneGraph before this. Although I think I am likely to go with CreatJS at this point in time.

Comment: As you wish. CreateJS is also a good one :) Just for information, cgSceneGraph offers a lot of features and is designed to be extended. So you are not bound to the framework and can do every render you need in a few time, even if the framework does not provide it natively. Each of your class will autmatically inherit of the framework. That's why it is really powerful and more flexible than the others, but that's my point of view, so I'm not sure to be totally objectiv :)

Comment: That is a very good point! So much of my code is custom that I really need the flexibility and extensibility, instead of being bound to a specific framework.

Comment: I took a second look at the examples and I am impressed. Beginning to change my mind about CreateJS and veering towards cgSceneGraph!

Comment: Thanks :) Feel free to ask any question. I'll be very glad to help :)